# How to attach event click to button Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I try to attach event click to button. For testing, i just want to change button text when click.

as I read from doc https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html. All QWidgets inherit QObject. Thats means all widget avaiable for signal and slot. Include this QPushButton.

But text in button not change. whats problem?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    window->setWindowTitle("Pandora");
    window->setFixedSize(640, 360);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(window);

    QPushButton *login = new QPushButton;
    login->setText("Login");

    QObject::connect(login, SIGNAL(clicked()), login, SLOT(setText("Change Success")));
    
    
    layout->addWidget(login);

    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: `QObject::connect(login, SIGNAL(clicked()), login, SLOT(setText("Change Success")));` please read again about signals and slots and fix your connect.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, the specific values of arguments can not be specified when creating a signal-slot connection.  So `"Change Success"` is not permitted.  You are likely getting an error message on the console indicating that no such slot exists.  The correct syntax is to indicate the argument **type**, not the value (e.g., `SLOT(setText(QString))`).

Secondly, the arguments of the signal and the slot must be compatible.  In this case, the `clicked()` signal provides no arguments and thus can not be connected to the `setText(QString)` slot.

Thirdly, you are using the legacy string-based connection syntax for signal-slot connections.  The functor-based syntax is preferred (refer to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html).

The quickest way to change the button text with a signal-slot connection is to use the functor syntax with a lambda (requires Qt5+):

```
connect(login, &QPushButton::clicked, [=]() { login->setText("Change Success"); });
```